# How many legs does a octopus have/has?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

> How many legs does an octopus have?
>
> How many legs does an octopus has?

If octopus is singular, why do we use "has" instead of "have"?

Comment: *why do we use "has" instead of "have"?* The short answer is ***We don't!*** This is "basic English".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**has**" is incorrect in this structure. The correct sentence is:

- How many legs does an octopus have?

The only way "**has**" can be correct is in this structure:

- How many legs has an octopus?

When we use the auxilary verb "**do**" in the interrogative it is always "**have**" with either plural or singular subject.

Comment: Octopus "legs" or "arms" would be understood by most folks. Tentacles in informal spoken English could seem awkward in some cases.

Comment: @ColleenV My god, is it really so different in English?